# "Усилия потрачены"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вдруг возникли сомнения: а правильно ли говорить, что "усилия *потрачены* (впустую)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оборот корректен, лексической несочетаемости нет. Усилия (силы) нормативно сочетаются с "тратить".